# Laravel mySQL database error "Unknown database"

Tags: laravel

Im trying to use the command php artisan migrate, however i keep getting the error:

```
PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'forge'
```

at first i got the:

```
access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'
```

but that was fixed when I changed the database.php and .env files to:

database.php

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

.env

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''
```

I read somewhere that I had to create the database in the mySQL database. If i do need to do this why is that, is there an alternative more effecient way from the command line. My development environment is Windows 7.

**UPDATE**
I have solved this error by going to localhost/phpmyadmin and creating a database with the same name and collation. But i still dont understand why i have to use phpmyadmin to create it, how would i be able to do this from the command line.

Also, inside this database i have tables for users, if i get more info from the users, do i create another database or just use a table with the values ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have all of your data contained in one database and have the user only have access to that table. The method you're trying to go through is not secure as you have to give laravel (or the app) permission to create any tables, delete any tables (to undo the tables created), and read any tables, which can get hairy in a environment that share a database with other applications.

It also goes to say that if the application doesn't adhere to a prefix naming of dbs it could make them at will and collide with another application since namespacing doesn't exist.

If however you really do need this functionality you can follow the guide written by Koster (http://laravel.io/forum/09-13-2014-create-new-database-and-tables-on-the-fly).